# Rails - Object attributes accessible individually but not by inspect method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model, controller

Sorry I'm new to rails but can't wrap my head around this one.

I have an Order object with various attributes - no references

In my controller I can print out the attributes individually via their attr_accessor and see them in the console via puts. 
But when I call .inspect they are all nil! any suggestions?

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :date, :dessert_type, :size, :quantity, :dessert, :comments, :total
  validates :name, :date, :quantity, presence: true
  validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0}
  validate :contact_provided?


  private
    def contact_provided?
      if :email.blank? || :phone.blank?
        errors.add(:base, "Please provide either phone or email so we can contact you!")
      end
    end
end
```

Controller

```
  def create_order

    puts "create_order object"
    @order = Order.new order_params

    if @order.valid?
      puts @order.inspect

      #everything is null here
      @order.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
        puts "#{attr_name}: #{attr_value}"
      end
      #this prints out fine!
      puts "dessert: #{@order.dessert}"
    end

  end
```

Parameters

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"randomtoken", "order"=>{"name"=>"jim", "email"=>"test@email.com", "phone"=>"12345678", "dessert_type"=>"Cake", "size"=>"25.0", "dessert"=>"Chocolate Caramel", "date"=>"2018-04-15", "quantity"=>"1", "comments"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit Order"}
```

Any insight much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because this line:

```
attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :date, :dessert_type, :size, :quantity, :dessert, :comments, :total
```

is overriding the Order attributes in the way Rails works with them. As working with Rails you don't need that declaration, so you can remove them as attr_accessor.

As Order is an ActiveRecord model, then the getters and setters are already generated by ActiveRecord for all of your object attributes.

What you're doing right now is defining all of your attributes, with the attr_accessor as virtual attributes which are attributes on the model that don't persist in the database, just "*an attribute not corresponding to a column in the database*".

Comment: Beautiful! I thought I had to declare them! I started out going through books but felt I was going through them mindlessly- feel like I'm learning a bit more by just making something. However can't help but feel I'm missing out on the basics also. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: You could take a look to [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) and [ActiveModel](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) basics.